# Solving Strong Mathematical Induction Sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm trying to work on the problem below, though I've hit a wall on how to proceed to prove the inductive step.

Suppose that $c_0,c_1,c_2\ldots$ is a sequence defined as follows: $$c_0=2,\, c_1=2,\, c_2=6,\, c_k=3c_{k-3}\,(k\geq3)$$

Prove that $c_n$ is even for each integer $n\geq0$.

Here is what I have so far:

1. Show that $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ are true.

   - $c_0=2$ and $2\geq0$ and $2\mid2$, so this is even.
   - $c_1=2$ and $2\geq0$ and $2\mid2$, so this is even.
2. Show that for every integer $k\geq1$, if $P(i)$ is true for each integer $i$ with $0\leq i\leq k$, then $P(k+1)$ is true.

   - Let $k$ be any integer with $k\geq1$, and suppose $c_i$ is even for each integer $i$ with $0\leq i\leq k$ [inductive hypothesis].
   - I must show that $c_{k+1}$ is even for each integer $k\geq0$.
   - Now $c_{k+1}=3c_{k-2}$...

...and this is where I do not understand how to proceed. Any tips on how I can finish solving this problem are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the underscore.   \$C_{k-3}\$ will render as $C_{k-3}$

Comment: Strong induction allows (if you need it) i) multiple base cases ii) an induction step that isn't an increase by *one* but an increase by any other useful jump.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $P(n)$ be the statement “$c_n$, $c_{n+1}$, $c_{n+2}$ are even”. We have $P(0)$ by assumption. Furthermore, $P(n)\Rightarrow P(n+1)$, since if $c_n$, $c_{n+1}$, $c_{n+2}$ are even, $c_{n+3}=3c_n$ must be even also. By induction, $P(n)$ is true for all $n$, which implies immediately that $c_n$ must be even for all $n$.

A more immediate solution would be to use @fleablood’s approach, but this one enables you to do this problem by pure, vanilla induction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both clarifying my question, and providing an answer. Embarrassingly I must say I am still trying to interpret these answers, which shows I need to do much more review over strong mathematical induction. If you don't mind answering this last question, how do I even interpret these "subset" numbers. Sorry if this makes no sense, but I have never really dealt with this "underscore" syntax, as evident by me not being able to describe it. I envy your understanding

Comment: We all started somewhere, don’t worry. As for the syntax, interpret it as just an indexed sequence of variables. $c_0$ is the zeroth variable, $c_1$ is the first, and so on. Other than the fact that you can reference a particular variable by a single whole number, you shouldn’t treat them any different than any other variable name.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ in your induction step.  Do $P(n)\implies P(n+3)$ (and that is *trivial*)

This is acceptable.

As $C_0$ is even then by induction $C_{3k}$ is even for all $k\in \mathbb N$.

And as $C_1$ is even then by induction $C_{1 + 3k}$ is even for all $k\in \mathbb N$.

And as $C_2$ is even then by induction $C_{2 + 3k}$ is even for all $k\in \mathbb N$.

So as any $n\in \mathbb N$ is either equal to $0,1,$ or $2$ plus some multiple of $3$ we are done.

.....

Assuming we have proven that $C_{n}$ is even means $C_{n+3}$ is even.  I leave that to you.  (Again... it is *trivial*.)

==========

Alternative explanation.

"Strong" induction means in the induction step you don't just assume $P(n)$ is true for $n=k$ but $P(n)$ is true for *all* $n \le k$.

So in this induction step:

Assume $C_n$ is even for all $n \le k$.  We must prove that $C_{k+1}$ is even.

And here it is:

$C_{k+1} = 3\times C_{k-2}$ and $k-2 < k$ so $C_{k-2}$ is even.  So $C_{k+1}$ is a multiple of an even number and is even.

That's it.  And that's fair.

In "weak" induction, we would have done something directly related to $C_k$.  But in "strong" induction we don't *have* to use $C_k$, we can use $C_{\text{anything less than or equal to }k}$.  In this case we use $C_{k-2}$.

Comment: Very good explanations!